# How to give a range of time in Spanish?

Tags: tiempo

So I want to say
"from an hour to an hour and a half".

I figure this should work:

"de una hora a una hora y una media"

I've been googling around and there isn't much depth discussion on this sort of expression. When I threw this phrase into an online spanish checker, it told me that I should remove the una before media.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the context I would say:

> De hora a hora y media.
>
> Entre hora y hora y media.

When you have `one` as the minimum of your time range and no more than `two` as the maximum, you can omit that in Spanish.

> De hora a hora y media.
>
> De una hora a dos horas y media.

But, on the other hand, when you have a different minimum, you can omit the time "unit":

> De tres a tres horas y media.
>
> De diez a veinte años.

Comment: I'd rather say "Entre hora **y** hora y media".

Comment: But if you want to say I have one hour, you have to say "una hora". Also, what about this phrase "De una hora a dos horas y media.", why did you keep the "una" there.

Comment: @Yay you're right. I've just corrected it.

Comment: @munchschair I cannot give you a technical explanation. It is just as we say that. I'll look for that explanation, if any.

Comment: That's totally understandable and a part of all natural language ^

Answer (score 0):

munchschair, you are confused with "una".

"Una" can be omitted or used before "hora" in any case.

If you think that "hora" is singular and "una" would force you to use "hora" in singular you know that "una" can be omitted if you want, so you can say

> Una hora y media.
>
> hora y media.

If you want to express a range of time the more used expressions are`de/a`, `desde/hasta` o `entre/y` like these:

> 1. Tengo **de** una hora **a** hora y media para llegar.
> 2. Para resolver el examen generalmente nos dan **desde** una hora **hasta** hora y media.
> 3. Para resolver el examen generalmente nos dan **entre** una hora **y** hora y media.

In all these examples you can omit "una"

For plural obviously you have to use the quantity and the plural "horas". For the same previous 3 examples we have.

> 1. .....**de** dos **a** tres horas....
> 2. .....**de** dos horas **a** tres.....
> 3. ....**desde** dos **hasta** tres horas
> 4. ...... **desde** dos horas **hasta** tres
> 5. .....**entre** dos horas **y** tres
> 6. .....**entre** dos **y** tres horas

In all these you can add "y media". i.e "dos horas y media"

What is wrong in your question is "una media". You should say "hora y media" "dos horas y media" or even "hora y cuarto" but never "dos horas y **una** media"

BTW. You could also move the placement of "horas". It is also valid to say "tengo dos y media **horas** para hacer la tarea"